# Registering new google.com recaptcha site with my heroku website raised error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, runtime-error, recaptcha

I have uploaded my project on **Heroku** and when my project on localhost google Recaptcha work good and now it shows me an error

> ERROR for site owner:
> Invalid domain for site key

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the Heroku domain in the Google Admin console, as you have probably already done with `localhost`.

Go to [Google Admin Console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/) and add in the Domains list for the site your application Heroku Url, for example `<myapp>.herokuapp.com`